# Exception sendo lançada ao utilizar a API Commons-email

Tags: java, envio-de-email, exceção, javamail

Estou tentando usar a [API Commons-Email](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/download_email.cgi) como alternativa a conhecida `JavaMail` para enviar emails em Java mas está ocorrendo um problema. Está sendo lançada a seguinte `Exception`:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/mail/Message at Main.main(Main.java:6)

O problema ocorre na linha 6 quando eu tento instanciar um objeto da classe `SimpleEmail`. Segue o meu código:

```
import org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail(); // ops?! Aqui é lançada a Exception
            email.setHostName("mail.foo.com");

            email.setFrom("rnxn@sopt.com", "rnxn") // remetente
                 .addTo("foo@bar.com", "Sr. Foo") // destinatário
                 .setMsg("Exception sendo lançada ao utilizar a API Commons-email") // corpo do email
                 .setSubject("StackOverflow"); // título

            email.send(); // envio

        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } 
    }
}
```

Fiz a importação corretamente de todos os arquivos **.jar** que vieram no download. Alguma solução para o tratamento deste problema?

Comment: isso é problemas de imports pelo menos comigo esse erro sempre apareceu por causa disso, ás vezes algumas das Lib's até está correcta mas está numa versao diferente da que é pedida...

Comment: O problema tem relação com o `import` mas não era por causa das versões. Mesmo assim eu agradeço o seu comentário.

Comment: Ta faltando jars ai... Ele ta falando q não encontrou a classe Message da javax.mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema ocorre porque a `Commons-email` não é uma API independente como eu pensava, trata-se de uma camada mais abstraída da `JavaMail API`, i.e. ela possui dependências.

A exceção lançada no meu código acontece pelo fato de não encontrar a classe `Message`, pertencente a `JavaMail` e não inclusa nos arquivos **.jar** da *commons*.

Para resolver o problema, bastou eu baixar a `JavaMail API` [por meio deste link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eeplat-419426.html#javamail-1.4.7-oth-JPR) e fazer o `import` dela no projeto juntamente com a `Commons-email`.